# highcharts graph no show yaxis values

Tags: highcharts

The graph does not show the y-axis values​​.  Could anyone help me with this? thanks.

If I put the value of `prueba` in the series data, everything worsk correctly
the `prueba` array and the `dinero` array are displayed correctly.

Thanks,

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/jquery/grafica4.php', function(data) {

    var dinero = [];
    var categories = [];
    var prueba = [79, 71, 66,44,42,38,32,10];

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        categories.push(data[index].producto_id);
        dinero.push(data[index].cantidad);
        alert("hola");
    });
    alert(dinero);
    alert(prueba);

    chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container3',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Productos más vendidos'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title:
            text: 'Cantidad'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        shadow: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ''+
            '<b>'+'Producto:'+this.x +'</b>'+'<br/>'+ this.y+ ' unidades';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Cantidad',
        data: dinero
    }],
    exporting: {
        filename: 'Facturacion-de-empleados'
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Can you log and show us your json result ?

Comment: i have result problem. the problem is casting (int)value in return json. thanks

Comment: If you believe you answered this question, make sure to create an answer, and mark it as such.